# Rails: how to get value of *_type in polymorphic association when target is using STI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

If I have:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :belongable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Bar < SuperBar
end

class SuperBar < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

and then do:

```
f = Foo.new :belongable => Bar.first
f.save
f.belongable_type # => SuperBar
f.belongable.type # => Bar
f.belongable.type.class.model_name
```

When using STI, ActiveRecord seems to set the belongable_type column to belongable's first subclass of ActiveRecord::Base.  Is there a method it uses on belongable to get that?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `belongable_type.class.base_class` does this.  See https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/08754f12e65a9ec79633a605e986d0f1ffa4b251/activerecord/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb#L100